# Lookup if cell contains one of many options and vlookup the result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of error message, and I want to consolidate them to their "user friendly" message:

```
      error        | friendly_error

failed with error1 | =VLOOKUP(A1, error_table, 1, false)
failed with error2 |
something else error3 |
error 4 failed with error5 |
failed with error1 |
```

And a table with the friendly values based on it containing of some keyword

```
contains | friendly_error
error1   | Message for error1
error2   | Message for error 2
etc...
```

Is there a command that can do this? Or do I need a bunch of if/else comments in a less organized way?

Vlookup would lookup the smaller value in a larger value, but I want to lookup a larger value to see if it contains a smaller value.

Right now I'm doing this, but it grows as I add more possible values:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G3,A1)),
    H3,
    IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G4,A1)),
        H4, 
        IF (ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G5,A1)),
            H5,
            A1
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Okay. Is there a question?

Comment: Remove `"failed with "` before performing the `VLOOKUP`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the error types are the actual Excel error types, you could use `Error.Type()`:

```
=VLOOKUP(ERROR.TYPE(A2),$E$1:$F$9,2,FALSE)
```

Where `A2` is the formula returning the error `#N/A`, `#REF!`, etc.

[image]

Edit: Or, if I completely misunderstood, just replace your `VLOOKUP()` with:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"failed with ",""), error_table, 1, false)
```

Assuming `A1`has `failed with error1` in it.

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately they're not excel error types, and I won't be able to substitute text since it can be located anywhere within the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this which iterates the Errors and tests if it is a substring of the errors in A.  Then returns the row number to the INDEX, which returns the correct Friendly Error.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G$1:$G$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1:$G$3,A2))),1)),"")
```

[image]